# parser package functionality in R > 3

Tags: r, parsing

It looks like most of the `parser` package functionality has been baked into R with the > 3 releases, but there is one bit that I'm particularly interested in that has been omitted:

> The id values are not attached to the elements of the parse tree, they are only retained in the table returned by getParseData.

Here by "attached to the elements" I'm assuming I could do something like:

```
x <- parse(text="...")
attr(x[[1]][[2]][[1]], "id")
```

to get the id that matches the one in `getParseData(x)`, though maybe that is not what is meant. I assume it is based on `parser` docs:

> The output is a list of expressions similar to the output of parse except that expressions are not associated with an inline srcref information. Instead, each expression has an id attribute that refers to the data.

Is there an alternate way to achieve this?  I'd prefer something on cran to do this if possible though I guess I could install `parser` from github (initial attempts failed with compilation errors, but I haven't spent much time debugging that).

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What sort of alternate way are you looking for, and why, if there is context?

Comment: @RobertKrzyzanowski The context is that I want to attach comments as attributes to the actual expression, but in order to do that I need to map `expr[[i]][[j]][[k]]` (this is just an example) to the corresponding token produced by `getParseData`.  This would have been trivial if the `id` from `getParseData` could be mapped to the expression resulting from `parse`. The alternate I'm looking for is some way of doing just this without having to do the mapping myself manually.